# Getting rows count on inner join rails scope

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, having

I have the following scope:

```
scope :billable, -> (range_start = nil, range_end = nil) {
    joins(:bids)
      .where("auctions.complete = 1 AND auctions.starts_at >= ? AND auctions.starts_at <= ? AND auctions.listing = 0", range_start, range_end)
      .group("auctions.id")
  }
```

I am trying to determine how to add a constrain to the where clause that allows me to select where count(bids) > auctions.items_count

Comment: Try `.having( "count(bids.id) > count(items.id)" )`

Answer (score 0):

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#having

Thing to keep in mind in SQL:

- The WHERE clause is for conditions on individual rows, *before* they have been put into groups by a GROUP BY.
- The HAVING clause is for conditions on groups.

You have a condition on which groups to include in the result, since your condition uses the aggregate function `count()`. So it belongs in the HAVING clause.